# In LiveCycle, what does it mean when an object name begins with #?

Tags: javascript, object, adobe, livecycle

Some objects' name in LiveCycle begin with # such as `form1.#variables[0].myVar` or in case I am dealing with now:

```
Page1.personalDetails.eyeColor.resolveNode("#bindItems[0]").labelRef
```

Why bindItems has a # ? What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

**.#
Matches a property. This is useful if both a property and a container have the same name; the .# insures that the property is accessed.
A.#B**

source: http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/xml/som_2.0.pdf

Answer (score 1):

it can also be used to reference an unnamed subform:

```
var x = xfa.form.form1.#subform.TextField1.rawValue;
```

Comment: then how does LiveCycle know which subform you are referring to?

Comment: isnt supposed to be like this:  xfa.form.form1.#subform[1].TechField.rawValue; ?

Comment: only if you had more than one subform you would need to refer to the index, starting with #subform[0]

Answer (score 0):

Edit: former answer was just simply wrong :P

Comment: Im not sure what does it have to do with CSS !!!, its in Livecycle, its JavaScript.

Comment: @Seeker I was saying it's possibly a css *selector* which is used in jquery (javascript toolkit) in things like $("#myDiv") which would select an element like `<div id="myDiv">`.  But I was wrong it seems :) so it's superfluous.